# How to center do_shortcode in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi people how can i center the output of:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[aps-counter]");?>
```

This line puts a counter out but it is left centered. Thank you very much !

Comment: This is "HTML/CSS 101" stuff.

Comment: ok lol i did it :d

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap the output in a container and use css to center it like so:

```
<?php echo "<div style='margin:0 auto;'>" . do_shortcode("[aps-counter]") . "</div>"; ?>
```